# Pandas set start and end based on consecutive category

Tags: python, pandas

So there are similar questions on stack overflow but none that quite address this and I can't really figure this one out. I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Account     Size
------------------
11120011     0
11130212     0
21023123     1
22109832     2
28891902     2
33390909     0
34123495     0
34490909     0
```

And for the all the accounts that have size==0 I'd like to collapse them like so:

```
 Account Start     Size     Account End
 ---------------------------------------
 11120011           0        11130212     
 21023123           1        21023123   
 22109832           2        22109832
 28891902           2        28891902     
 33390909           0        34490909
```

The Accounts with size!=0 can just repeat in both columns but for the ones with size=0 I'd just like to keep the beginning and end of that particular segment. The df is sorted on Account already.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, using `diff` + `cumsum` create the groupkey , then do `agg`

```
m1=df.Size.diff().ne(0)
m2=df.Size.ne(0)
df.groupby((m1|m2).cumsum()).agg({'Account':['first','last'],'Size':'first'})
Out[97]: 
      Size   Account          
     first     first      last
Size                          
1        0  11120011  11130212
2        1  21023123  21023123
3        2  22109832  22109832
4        2  28891902  28891902
5        0  33390909  34490909
```

Comment: So this almost gets me there but I only want this to happen for rows where size = 0, for any other size the same account should just repeat in first and last.

Comment: That did it! If you don't mind could you explain how this works? Especially the aggregation on the groupby object. Thank you so much!

Comment: @doddy you can check with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html,,about the first and last , first slice the 1st value for each group , last slice the last one

Comment: @doddy for m1 : get the different from size, and if they are not the same return True, m1| m2 only not increase the groupbykey when it is size is 0

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I think this also works.

`df['Account End'] = df.shift(-1)[(df.Size == 0)]['Account']`

Still in the learning phase for pandas, if this is bad for any reason let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi this won't work because it only shifts by one. There could be thousands of consecutive rows with size=0. Not sure if that is clear enough but you could try it and it'll make more sense.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see what you mean. You need to group all consecutive rows of size 0, not just two.

Comment: Now I see why the answer above is necessary! Ha.